# ZTE F670L most setting disappeared, can't edit some, reset button doesn't factory reset router. But the Internet works completely fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My Internet works perfectly fine. But I can't configure my router, I can change some things but most of the options have vanished, and it automatically created one SSID named "NET+Roaming" I can't even change the password for that (though for my original SSIDs, I can.). I cannot access the list of wireless devices connected to my router. While holding the reset button (which previously resets the router after blinking of all LEDs) it just blinks 2 LEDs and does nothing, It just reconnects my devices and nothing has changed.

Example of change in setting, Before (taken from internet):

router setting with so many options:

[image: router setting with so many options]

Screenshot with almost all settings vanished:

[image]

Comment: Is your router owned by your ISP?

Comment: If the router isn't owned by the ISP, there's only three reasons why a reset button on a router wouldn't work: (1) improper timing/not following timing steps _(e.g. varies by OEM, but things such as holding it down for 15s - 45s, holding it down while plugging in the router, etc. - see router's manual/ZTE's support site)_; (2) button has failed _(highly unlikely)_; (3) firmware is corrupted _(save router configuration to a file then re-flash firmware)_

Comment: Yes, my router is owned by my ISP, and I'd Like to know how to save my configuration, and any link to flashing process/files would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue on my ZTE device. It belongs to **Netplus** ISP. They have pushed a new firmware to lock the router down. Generally ISPs do this to avoid technical burden from non-technical users but for a poweruser this is a bit of let down.

I have tried to reset the router but it does not flush these settings.

Try contacting the customer support for your ISP.

Comment: Actually my ISP is also Netplus, did they respond and resolve this issue for you after contacting them?

Comment: They did not resolve anything. The customer care representative cared about closing the ticket ASAP. Ask them that you want to do port forwarding else it might strongly impact your work.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me last week. Just as the answer by Bhavy Madan mentioned, they remotely updated the firmware. You can login using 'user' as both username and password but the settings are quite limited. To get the complete access like before, we would need to find out the admin account credentials. I'm hoping to ask my local provider and will share them here if I manage to get them. Meanwhile, I urge you to do the same- Ask your local provider for the credentials stating that you need to change some important settings for your cameras to work, as this is the only solution.

Comment: I see, I'll talk to them about this and try to get the credentials.

Comment: Hey, did any of you manage to get the new credentials?